# asp.net c# Controller acting weird

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

First of, the name of this question is not very good but I could not think of a better one.
I'm working a project where I report hours perday, and on diffrent projects.

This is how it looks like. 
[image]

But the problem is now, if I would submit it it would end up like this.

[image]

Like we can see here on the summary of the month, that on the secound date it duplicates the project and shows it up twice, this happends if I add more dates as well. **But it never happends on the first date.**

I've been debugging it, but I do not see any diffrent behavior from when it were ran the first time, all the values are the same etc.

This is the controller

```
public ActionResult TimeReport(FormCollection form, Guid? id)
    {
        ViewDataDictionary vd = new ViewDataDictionary
        {
            ["projects"] = new DatabaseLayer().GetConsultantProjects(Constants.CurrentUser(User.Identity.Name)),
            ["id"] = 1,
            ["showDescription"] = true
        };
        ViewData["vd"] = vd;

        NewTimeReportModel projectData = new NewTimeReportModel();

        if (form != null && form.AllKeys.Contains("delete"))
        {
            new DatabaseLayer().DeleteTimeReport(Guid.Parse(form["ReportId"]));
            LoadDefaultSettings(projectData);
            ViewData.Model = projectData;
            return View();
        }

        if (id.HasValue && (form == null || form.AllKeys.Length == 0))
        {
            using (DatabaseLayer db = new DatabaseLayer())
            {
                var timeReport = db.GetTimeReport(id.Value);
                projectData = new NewTimeReportModel(timeReport);
                if (projectData.Projects.Count == 1)
                    projectData.Projects[0].Hours = null;
            }
        }
        else if (form == null || form.AllKeys.Length == 0)
        {
            LoadDefaultSettings(projectData);
        }
        else
        {
            //Takes all the dates that is being sent from the view and put into a string.
            string input = (form["date"]);
            input = input.Trim();
            string[] dates = input.Split(' ');

            //Foreach to loop over all the dates, also rebuilds the string to look like yy-mm-dd so we can parse it to a datetime
            foreach (string result in dates.Select(date => date.Substring(0, 2) + '-' + date.Substring(2, 2) + "-" + date.Substring(4, 2)))
            {
                DateTime reportDate;
                if (!DateTime.TryParse(result, out reportDate))
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("Date", "Felaktikt datum");
                }

                var projectNumbers = (from x in form.AllKeys
                    where x.Contains("_")
                    select x.Substring(x.IndexOf('_'))).Distinct();

                projectData.Times = new TimeReportTimes(form["startTime"], form["endTime"], form["breakTime"], ModelState);
                projectData.Date = reportDate;

                //Checks to see if we did choose a project.
                var enumerable = projectNumbers as string[] ?? projectNumbers.ToArray();
                if (!enumerable.Any())
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("Projekt", "Inga projekt valda...");
                }
                else
                {
                    int emptyHours = 0;

                    foreach (string projectNumber in enumerable)
                    {

                        projectData.Projects.Add(new NewTimeReportModel.Project
                        {
                            Description = form["description" + projectNumber],
                            Hours = null,
                            ProjectId = Guid.Parse(form["project" + projectNumber])
                        });

                        string hourString = form["hours" + projectNumber];
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hourString))
                        {
                            emptyHours++;
                            projectData.Projects[projectData.Projects.Count - 1].Hours =
                                projectData.Times.WorkedHours;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (!projectData.Projects[projectData.Projects.Count - 1].SetHours(hourString))
                            {
                                ModelState.AddModelError("hours_" + projectNumber, "Felaktig antal timmar");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //Checks so the hours are right.
                    if (emptyHours > 1 || (emptyHours == 0 && projectData.Projects.Sum(x => x.Hours) != projectData.Times.WorkedHours))
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("hours_" + enumerable.First(),
                            "Antalet timmar stämmer ej överrens");
                    }

                    //Checks so the worked hours is bigger than 0
                    if (projectData.Projects.Any(x => x.Hours <= 0))
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("hours_" + enumerable.First(),
                            "Antalet timmar måste vara större än noll");
                    }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(form["ReportId"]))
                    { 
                        projectData.ReportId = Guid.Parse(form["ReportId"]);
                    }

                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        //saves the report to the database
                        projectData.SaveToDatabase(Constants.CurrentUser(User.Identity.Name));
                        //Saves ViewData To true so we know in the view it's been posted.
                        ViewData["posted"] = true;

                        projectData = new NewTimeReportModel();
                        LoadDefaultSettings(projectData);
                    }
                    else if (projectData.Projects.Count == 1)
                    { 
                        projectData.Projects[0].Hours = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var missingdays = new DatabaseLayer().GetConsultantMissingDays(Constants.CurrentUser(User.Identity.Name));
        if (missingdays.Count == 0)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.MissingDays = missingdays;
        }

        ViewData.Model = projectData;

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: A good first step to debugging this would be to break certain components out from your Action into separate, smaller methods. A method should have a single responsibility; this will make them more testable and easier to read/debug.

Comment: I kinda know what's wrong now, I have it setup so I can set settings for me such as start hour, start project etc. and if I add a start project in the settings it will act this way. But if I manualy press Add Project while reporting the time it will work like it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasen't do strange, at the very end of the foreach loop I had this if statement

```
                        if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        projectData.SaveToDatabase(Constants.CurrentUser(User.Identity.Name));
                        ViewData["posted"] = true;

                        //Loads default settings and projects.
                        projectData = new NewTimeReportModel();
                        LoadDefaultSettings(projectData);

                    }
```

This last like `LoadDefaultSettings(projectData);` loads all the settings again, so after it saved the first date, it did load all the settings again for the next date. There for they got duplicated. So I did just move that out of the foreach.